# Как можно получить размер файла

Tags: c++, файлы, файловая-система

Я получаю параметры с командной строки cmd и вывожу их, затем нужно найти в этой папке с которой запущен скрипт файл с наибольшим размером, вопрос как можно получить размер файла?

```
#include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<argc;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Argument"<<i<<":"<<argv[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартная библиотека [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem). Можно прочесть содержимое каталога с помощью `directory_iterator`, как набор `directory_entry`, у которого есть функция-член `file_size()`, возвращающая размер файла...

А дальше - просто найти максимальный.

Простейший пример -

```
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main()
{
    for(auto& p: fs::directory_iterator(".."))
    {
        std::cout
            << p.path() << " has size "
            << p.file_size() << " bytes" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Ну, а найти максимальный и вывести - это уж вы самостоятельно :)

Comment: for (directory_iterator itr(directory_entry); itr!=directory_iterator(); ++itr)
 {
  
 }
Это правильная запись?

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста пример кода

Comment: Ну вот, см. кусочек в ответе...

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли